# HP Pavilion dv6748us: Dummy Output on Linux Mint 20.3

Tags: linux, audio, drivers, linux-mint, hp-pavilion

I recently installed Linux Mint on this HP Pavilion dv6748us laptop to use as my main "portable" device aside my phone.
Up until now, it was a nightmare to set all up. Given that it has an nvidia nForce 630M chipset, sourching the propietary drivers and patching them to work with the latest available linux version was also kinda hard. I had (and have) all kind of issues that I've been able to fix (and want to fix) along the process, but I have no clue on what to do with Audio.
I tried with three different distros: Ubuntu 22.04, Zorin 16.3 and Linux Munt 20.3 (xfce) and 21.1 (cinnamon). All of them had the same main issue: Dummy Output. No matter what I try, I cannot get any sort of analog audio (neither from the speakers or the dual headphone output) to reproduce. I know that I have at least some kind of audio output, since the BIOS does make the "beep" sound, but thats it.
I have followed the [Tips for Troubleshooting Sound Issues](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=389383) guide, but I got kind of lost since I got some messages I dont know what they mean. Here is what I did so far:

> Run `inxi -Axxx` in a terminal to verify the drivers are installed.

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~$ inxi -Axxx
Audio:
  Message: No Device data found.
```

> Run `aplay -l` in a terminal to verify the sound cards are recognized.

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:276: no soundcards found...
```

> To help with troubleshooting, run the following in a terminal:
> `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"`

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~$ journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"
abr 29 15:52:35 FPP-dv6000 kernel: ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
```

> The terminal output of `pacmd list-sinks` while a song or video is
> playing on your computer

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~/.config/pulse$ pacmd list-sinks
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 68406 / 104% / 1,12 dB,   front-right: 68406 / 104% / 1,12 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 3,70 ms
    max request: 4 KiB
    max rewind: 4 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Estéreo
    used by: 1
    linked by: 1
    configured latency: 23,22 ms; range is 0,50 .. 2000,00 ms
    module: 13
    properties:
        device.description = "Salida ficticia"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Regarding SOF, when trying to install it, it aborts the installation and says that there are files under the install directory. I verified, and yes, there are files, but not like the ones from SOF...

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~/Descargas/sof-bin-v2.2.4$ sudo ./install.sh v2.2.4
+ ln -sT sof-v2.2.4 /lib/firmware/intel/sof
ln: fallo al crear el enlace simbólico '/lib/firmware/intel/sof': El archivo ya existe
+ set +x
./install.sh ERROR: /lib/firmware/intel/sof already installed? (Re)move it first.
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~/Descargas/sof-bin-v2.2.4$ ls /lib/firmware/intel/sof
sof-adl.ri    sof-byt.ri  sof-cnl.ri  sof-icl.ri   sof-skl.ri    v1.4.2
sof-adl-s.ri  sof-cfl.ri  sof-ehl.ri  sof-imx8.ri  sof-sue.ri    v1.6
sof-apl.ri    sof-cht.ri  sof-glk.ri  sof-jsl.ri   sof-tgl-h.ri  v1.6.1
sof-bdw.ri    sof-cml.ri  sof-hsw.ri  sof-kbl.ri   sof-tgl.ri    v1.9.2
```

Any suggestions?
One important thing: After digging through some manuals, I've found that I have a Realtek ALC861-VD-GR HD Audio IC... I dont know if its useful info or not...

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~/Descargas/sof-bin-v2.2.4$ inxi -Frzxxx
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-147-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.4.0 
           Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 tk: Gtk 3.24.20 info: xfce4-panel wm: xfwm4 
           dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.3 Una base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Hewlett-Packard product: HP Pavilion dv6700 Notebook PC 
           v: Rev 1 serial: <filter> Chassis: Quanta type: 10 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: Quanta model: 30CF v: 85.26 serial: <filter> BIOS: Hewlett-Packard 
           v: F.34 date: 03/22/2011 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 20.4 Wh condition: 29.7/55.1 Wh (54%) volts: 12.5/10.8 
           model: Hewlett-Packard Primary type: Li-ion serial: <filter> status: Charging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: AMD Turion 64 X2 Mobile TL-60 bits: 64 type: MCP 
           arch: K8 rev.F+ rev: 2 L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 svm bogomips: 8000 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/2000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA C67 [GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M] vendor: Hewlett-Packard 
           driver: nvidia v: 304.137 bus ID: 00:12.0 chip ID: 10de:0531 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nvidia compositor: compton 
           v: 0.1~beta2+20150922 resolution: 1280x800~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 7150M / nForce 630M/integrated/SSE2 
           v: 2.1.2 NVIDIA 304.137 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Message: No Device data found. 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-147-generic 
Network:   Device-1: NVIDIA MCP67 Ethernet vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: forcedeth 
           v: kernel port: 30f8 bus ID: 00:0a.0 chip ID: 10de:054c 
           IF: enp0s10 state: down mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n 
           vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: b43-pci-bridge v: N/A port: 30f8 
           bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 14e4:4328 
           IF-ID-1: wlan0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 149.05 GiB used: 18.61 GiB (12.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Hitachi model: HTS542516K9SA00 size: 149.05 GiB 
           speed: 1.5 Gb/s serial: <filter> rev: C32P temp: 47 C scheme: MBR 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 145.16 GiB used: 18.61 GiB (12.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 66 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Repos:     No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list 
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list 
           1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
           Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list 
           1: deb https://mint.zero.com.ar/mintpackages una main upstream import backport
           2: deb http://ubuntu.unc.edu.ar/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
           3: deb http://ubuntu.unc.edu.ar/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
           4: deb http://ubuntu.unc.edu.ar/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
           5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
           6: deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ focal partner
Info:      Processes: 193 Uptime: 45m Memory: 2.79 GiB used: 1.15 GiB (41.0%) 
           Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.4.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash 
           v: 5.0.17 running in: xfce4-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

***EDIT:*** I've been playing a little bit with some drivers that I found [here](https://www.hwdrivers.com/drivers/001543?device=scard&vendor=realtek&model=alc861-vd-gr)

For all the things I did, I used the "latest"(?) version of the driver (5.17). I read through the PDF and readme.txt with the build instructions. I had some issues with the "version.h" file not being in the specified directory, so I ran this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/linux/version.h
```

and it fixed the error:
[Output](https://pastebin.pl/view/004a2d2b)

./configure ran with no errors.

Now, with make. I had to run sudo make, otherwise it would give me permission errors. Also, it seems that there is a missing file called "relocs_32.c", and that stops the build:
[Output](https://pastebin.pl/view/ff682265)

After searching for a bit, I found that I had to modify the makefile. I had to look for a "SUBDIRS=$" and change it for "M=$". That seemd to work, until more errors appeared:
[Output](https://pastebin.pl/view/2c4f9380)

These seem to be way to specific, so I dont know if searching will help me...

I also tried with the other version thats available on the rar file. The 5.16. This one was a bit different. I didn't had to modify the makefile, but I got a different error:
[Output](https://pastebin.pl/view/e033515f)

I tried to apply the pathes and fixes recommended [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851433/kernel-doesnt-support-pic-mode-for-compiling), but I was unable to. I got this error:

```
fpp@FPP-dv6000:~/Descargas/ALC861-VD/realtek-linux-audiopack-5.16/alsa-driver-1.0.24$ patch < mkfile.patch
patching file Makefile
Hunk #1 FAILED at 608.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file Makefile.rej
```

[Makefile.rej](https://pastebin.pl/view/5a89146f)

Thats what I did so far.

Comment: You're using all the wrong distros. Your hardware is too old so perhaps you should try AntiX instead. It may not solve the audio issue though.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, tried AntiX 22 live. Still no sound. After looking for a while, i found [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/sound/hd-audio/models.html#alc861-660). Does N/A mean that ALSA does not support my card? I also found [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.1.10/source/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt). Its the latest kernel version that has something different than N/A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got solved after installing windows and installing the correspondig audio driver and booting back to linux...

EDIT: After the issue appearing again, I did some deeper investigation. It seems like the bios is doing some stuff wrong while setting up the audio codec and makes it unusable until its set up by windows again or manually resetted (I guess).

My permanent fix that does not rely on windows was to install an "unlocked" bios, that lets me disable the audio codec. When I get the same issue again, I just disable the audio codec, reboot to bios, enable it again, and just boot to linux back again.